# Release upgrading 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS breaks mysql-server 5.7?

Tags: server, upgrade, mysql, do-release-upgrade

L.s.

I work for a managed hosting company and because of Ubuntu 16.04 has gone EOL we are pushing our clients to dist-upgrade their servers. Most clients preffer the least amount of downtime and want to upgrade to the latest version (Ubuntu 20.04) so they are supported for the next 4 years.

Recentley I upgraded a dedicated database server running the latest mysql-server-5.7 provided by the official Ubuntu repository. I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 without major problems and everything was working. During the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 I was asked if I wanted to remove the /var/lib/mysql directory, this caught me of guard but I chose to keep the directory. After finishing the release upgrade mysql-server-5.7 was removed and only mysql-server-8 was available in the official repository.

I did get MySQL 8 running, I had to remove some config options in /etc/mysql/* which were no longer supported. I was able to access the databases using the mysql command line utility. Unfortunately I could not login to PHPMyAdmin anymore which was important to the client and also since this is probably not a supported upgrade path I was afaraid the database might no longer be consistent. I decided to restore the snapshot of 18.04 with mysql 5.7.

I have a client that wants to upgrade his acceptance server to 20.04 with MySQL 8, he is cool with it if it breaks and they are capable enough to help out from their end. I will try and upgrade their server this friday like I did with the previous server, I am curious if the databases will be consistent.

Is there a supported way of upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and upgrade mysql 5.7 to 8.x?

Comment: If you use the official MySQL repo instead of the Ubuntu repo, version 5.7 is still supported ([see here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-focal/)).

Comment: Also, maybe you should rephrase your question. As I read it, you actually did get MySQL 8.0 to work, but the problem was PHPMyAdmin. Maybe refocus your question, if getting PHPMyAdmin to run with MySQL 8 is the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: @ArturMeinild The problem was I did not trust the database anymore, I was unsure if it was consistent or not. 

The normal upgrade pocedure for MySQL is to upgrade to the latest minor version, then do the major upgrade and on first startup the databases will be upgraded to the new format. But if this was supported I would expect the  do-release-upgrade to take care of this for me especially since the mysql-server meta package was installed.

The PHPMyAdmin problem was what convinced me to rollback, if the PHPMyAdmin is broken most likely the clients webapp will also have issues.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I will look into the MySQL repo, but officially third party repos are disabled for a do-release-upgrade. So it will break during an upgrade but can then be reinstalled to fix it. I can't imagine that this is the intended upgrade path.

Comment: Yes I would also always test the upgrade path on a VM first, especially with third-party repos.

Comment: This was on a VM and I made snapshots at the start, after each upgrade and even made snapshots of the non working upgrade. This is what saved me, I just reverted to 18.04 which was working. I just was unaware that MySQL 5.7 was unavailable in the Ubuntu 20.04 repo otherwise I would have done a proper test on a clone. But even knowing it I wouldn't expect the do-release-upgrade to blatently remove  MySQL server.